# Rank of ideal sheaf of a curve in $\mathbb{P}^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $Z$ be a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^3$ with pure codimension 2. Have one an exact sequence $$0\longrightarrow\mathscr{I}_Z\longrightarrow\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}\longrightarrow\mathscr{O}_Z\longrightarrow0$$ over $\mathbb{P}^3$. Why is one the rank of $\mathscr{I}_Z$? Is $c_{1}(\mathscr{O}_{Z}) = 0$ ? Where $c_{1}$ denotes the First class of Chern.

Comment: Because th rank is computed at the general point, and the general point lis away from $Z$.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I do not understand your answer.

Comment: How can I explicitly prove that the rank of ideal sheaf of $Z$ is one? I thank you for your help.

Comment: What precisely you don't understand? Do you know the definition of the rank? Do you know what is the general point? Do you know how to work with exact sequences?

Comment: Dear Sasha. 
I know the rank definition and I also know how to work with exact sequences.  I do not know what a general point is. Thank you.

Comment: Then how do you define rank?

Comment: This is a wrong definition. You will get a correct one if you replace $X$ by some Zariski open subset of $X$ (or be the general point). Then, coming back to your original question, just take this set to be the complement of $Z$.